# Google Analytics API V4 runRealtimeReport with v1Beta - cannot get source, medium, url

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We are running into the following problem;
We now request the v3 realtime endpoint for v3-properties. These requests contain the visited urls with source, medium and timestamp (minutesAgo). Since some of the v3-properties are transformed to v4-properties, we are exploring the [runRealtimeReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/runRealtimeReport)-endpoint. But this doesn't seem to provide in this information.

**My questions:**

1. How can we get the visited url, medium (ex. referral) and source (ex. google.com)? If this is not possible, when will it become possible?
2. Also, is there a depreciation-date known for the v3-beta-realtime-endpoint?